# Aggregate a collection of timestamps in MongoDB using the Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a collection of timestamps which record what actions are performed by users at which time. For now, the collection consists of only two actions `start` and `end`. There can only be a single `end` action, while there can be multiple `start` actions per user.

Now I want a generate a list of users where the time difference between the last `start` action and the `end` action is - for example - less than a minute.

The simplified documents in my collection `timestamps` look like this:

`document #1`

```
{
  id: 123,
  user: "user1",
  type: "start",
  date: 2019-09-10
}
```

`document #2`

```
{
  id: 234,
  user: "user1",
  type: "end",
   date: 2019-09-11
}
```

Now the result I want should look like this:

```
{
  id: null,
  list: ["user1, user2"]
}
```

The field `list` should contain every user, where the time difference between the `start` and `end` action is less than a minute.

I am having trouble combining the documents which contain the `start` and `end` attribute. I was trying to combine them into documents that looks like this:

```
{
  id: 345
  user: "user1"
  date_start: 2019-09-10
  date_end: 2019-09-11
}
```

I don't know where to start with the aggregation pipeline and how to split and combine the different types of timestamps. Furthermore, I still need to add a field that contains the difference between both dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort:{
            "date":-1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "id":"$id",
                "type":"$type"
            },
            "id":{
                $first:"$id"
            },
            "user":{
                $first:"$user"
            },
            "type":{
                $first:"$type"
            },
            "date":{
                $first:"$date"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$id",
            "user":{
                $first:"$user"
            },
            "info":{
                $push:{
                    "k":"$type",
                    "v":"$date"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "info":{
                $arrayToObject:"$info"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $lt:[
                    {
                        $subtract:[
                            {
                                $toDate:"$info.end"
                            },
                            {
                                $toDate:"$info.start"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    60000
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "users":{
                $push:"$user"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d598214"),
    "id" : 123,
    "user" : "user1",
    "type" : "start",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:01:14.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d598215"),
    "id" : 123,
    "user" : "user1",
    "type" : "start",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:04:14.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d598216"),
    "id" : 123,
    "user" : "user1",
    "type" : "start",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:09:02.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d598217"),
    "id" : 123,
    "user" : "user1",
    "type" : "end",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:09:14.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d598218"),
    "id" : 234,
    "user" : "user2",
    "type" : "start",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:02:02.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d598219"),
    "id" : 234,
    "user" : "user2",
    "type" : "end",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:09:14.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d59821a"),
    "id" : 345,
    "user" : "user3",
    "type" : "start",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:08:55.242Z"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a117bd4e75c58d59821b"),
    "id" : 345,
    "user" : "user3",
    "type" : "end",
    "date" : "2019-09-10T13:09:14.242Z"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "users" : [ "user3", "user1" ] }
```

**Query analysis:**

- **Stage I:** Sorting the documents in descending order of the date
- **Stage II:** Grouping on `[id, type]` and picking the first date for
  each type i.e. the latest date for each type
- **Stage III:** Grouping only on `id` and pushing the type and associated date into an array as key-value pairs
- **Stage IV:** Converting the array of key-value pairs into an object
- **Stage V:** Filtering documents which has the difference between end and start date less than 60000 ms. (milliseconds equivalent of 1 minute)
- **Stage VI:** Pushing all filtered names into an array

Comment: Thank you very much for this query and explanation! For some reason the match-Stage did not work in MongoDB Compass. I replaced it with a redact-Stage to remove the documents with the same condition.